MarkerCluster Upgrade Issue
Is there any way to replicate the clustering behavior of the previous version's default algorithm in the latest MarkerClusters version? I am unable to achieve the exact grouping of clusters after upgrading to the new version of MarkerClusters.
I tried adjusting the parameter gridSize to 60. With this value, I achieved a result close to that of the previous version, but still there is too much difference between them.
